# Content not showing on page using ListView

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to show data from database using ListView but the nothing would show on the page even though database has data

views.py

```
class CatAdoption(ListView):
    model = Cat
    template_name = 'adoptions/adoptionhome.html'
    context_object_name = 'cats'
```

urls.py

```
from .views import CatAdoption, DogAdoption, OtherAdoption

urlpatterns = [
    path('adoption-home/', CatAdoption.as_view(), name='adoptionhome'),
```

adoptionhome.html

```
{% extends 'home/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
        <div class="adoptionPara">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam officia commodi reprehenderit porro dolorum inventore alias maxime. 
        </div>
        <div class="animalTab" onclick="">
            <div class="animalCategoryTab">
                <img src="{% static 'adoptions/imgs/adoption-dog.png' %}">
                <span>Dogs</span>
            </div>
            <div class="animalCategoryTab" onclick="">
                <img src="{% static 'adoptions/imgs/adoption-cat.png' %}">
                <span>Cats</span>
            </div>
            <div class="animalCategoryTab" onclick="">
                <img src="{% static 'adoptions/imgs/adoption-others.png' %}">
                <span>Others</span>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="animals">
        {% for animals in cats  %}
            <div class="animalpictures">
                <div class="animalInfo">
                    <img alt="animalPic" src="https://1590597482.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="animalDesc">
                        <h1>{{ animals.name }}</h1>
                        <p>{{ animals.description }}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

(I have same code for another blog page which shows all contents from database)

Comment: Did you use *template inheritance*?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I have

Comment: are you sure you have a `{% block %}` that is actually in the inherited template? If you define this in a non-existing block, or outside a block, it will not "emit" the result in the final response.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've edited the html code, i think everything is the way it should be.

Comment: and the `home/base.html` has a `{% block content %}`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes.